# how to share a canvas background image between functions?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm trying to make a image viewer, this viewer can control the brightness and contrast of the image with sliders; but, when I use one slider to change the brightness of the image it changes the brightness, but then I change the contrast with the other slider it changes the contrast of the original image, not the one that I changed the brightness of.
This is my code:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = 934;
  canvas.height = 622;

  var background = new Image();
  background.src = "data:image/png;base64,{{ imgExtract }}";

  background.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    rangeBrillo.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
      if (rangeBrillo.value !== rangeBrilloOldVal) {
        setBrightness(Number(rangeBrillo.value));
      }
      rangeBrilloOldVal = Number(rangeBrillo.value);
    });
    rangeContraste.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
      if (rangeContraste.value !== rangeContrasteOldVal) {
        setContraste(Number(rangeContraste.value));
      }
      rangeContrasteOldVal = Number(rangeContraste.value);
    });
  };
  function setBrightness(value) {
    ctx.filter = `brightness(${value + 100}%)`;
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    background = background;
  }
  var rangeBrilloOldVal;
  function setContraste(value) {
    ctx.filter = `contrast(${value + 100}%)`;
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    background = background;
  }
  var rangeContrasteOldVal;
  var background;
```

I tried saving the `background` image in a variable at the end of each function but it didn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you redrawing canvas each time with original image.

```
ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
```

Save result into buffer image and use this image imstead of original or do more complex pixel manipalations with

```
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9rbc86gd/

here is more
[examples](https://img.ly/blog/how-to-apply-filters-in-javascript/)